# Specifying docker image from docker hub in docker compose file

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

I have docker compose file, where i would like to specify couple of local images and remote image

Below is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  productsservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productsservice         <-- local image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProductsService/Dockerfile

  dockercomposeapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockercomposeapi        <-- local image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerComposeAPI/Dockerfile

  ordersservice:
    image: myrepo/ordersservice                       <-- remote image
```

After running the docker compose from Visual Studio, below is the error we see in the output window

> Pulling ordersservice (myrepo/ordersservice:)...manifest for myrepo/ordersservice:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
> A non-critical error occurred while getting containers ready.  Your project will continue to function normally. The error was: manifest for myrepo/ordersservice:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
> If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.

We do have the ordersservice with *latest* tag. Could you please help how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

myrepo/ordersservice is this a public or private image ? can you pull it without any problems using 'docker pull' ? if not you need to do 'docker login' first

Comment: It is a public repo, and i can pull it without any issues

Comment: fine! and what about running 'docker-compose pull' not from the VS ? docker-compose pull --verbose --file file.yaml

Comment: If it's a public repo, why censor the name?

Comment: Image is madhuraju/ordersservice

Comment: Any help on this issue? I see image is getting pulled, but while starting the image it is failing. But no message in the logs.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the image, i was able to start a container from it via docker-compose. Could you please try to specify the tag but not 'latest' in your docker-compose file and try again?